# Do Apple review an app update when the original version isn't released yet?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, updates

One week ago apple approved my app and it will be sent on AppStore on December 10. But I found a big bug in my first version, so I have fixed it and sent an update. I would like to know if apple reviews updates before an app is published or not ?

Comment: This should probably be asked on the [developer forums](http://devforums.apple.com), not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They review every update. (That would be a pretty huge loophole otherwise!)